# MySQL 5.7 error (1093: You can't specify target table ___ for update in FROM clause) - usual solution not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

I have a table 'employees' and I'm trying to set some attributes (e.g. salary) to the same value as some other value in the table. My understanding of this error is that it can be avoided with the following workaround, using a temporary table:

```
UPDATE employees
SET salary=(SELECT salary FROM (SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_id= '123') AS t1)
WHERE employee_id='456';
```

However, I am still getting the same error code ("can't specify target table 'employees' for update in FROM clause") when I try this. Is there some other issue here?

Comment: It's working on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e840c/2)

Comment: Is there some reason it wouldn't be working on MySQL if it's supposed to..? I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: because though it is not an update with a join on same table it needs different aliases perhaps ?

Comment: Server version 5.7.9, workbench version 6.3.5

Answer (score 2):

The issue is a [functional change](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) in mysql 5.7,scroll towards the end

> The optimizer now handles derived tables and views in the FROM clause
>   in consistent fashion to better avoid unnecessary materialization and
>   to enable use of pushed-down conditions that produce more efficient
>   execution plans. However, for statements such as DELETE or UPDATE that
>   modify tables, using the merge strategy for a derived table that
>   previously was materialized can result in an ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED
>   error:

Either use the JOIN or force the otimizer to behave like in the previous version with:

```
SET optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge=off';
```

Comment: To be clear, that line would just go above the query, right? Based on that documentation it seems like it absolutely should work with that, but it still doesn't..

Comment: @filaments Run it separately before running the query.Doesnt work means what?

Comment: Still getting the same error message ("You can't specify target table 'employees' for update in FROM clause"). I ran it separately before the query.

I guess I can just use join and be done with it, but I wish I could figure this part out too.

Comment: @filaments Strange,try adding a DISTINCT after the outer SELECT to force the derived table.

Comment: Same error code still. I may be living in some weird parallel MySQL universe.