# MySQL 5.7 Update Error: 1093

Tags: mysql

I have this update statement in a trigger in one of my Databases:

```
UPDATE trainees 
SET rsi_total = (
  SELECT SUM(RsiTotal) as RsiTotal 
  FROM (
    SELECT MAX(hours) as RsiTotal 
    FROM courses 
      LEFT JOIN do_not_add ON courses.fk_class_id = do_not_add.fk_class_id 
      INNER JOIN trainees ON courses.FK_TRAINEES_ID = trainees.PK_TRAINEE_ID 
    WHERE do_not_add.fk_class_id IS NULL 
      AND trainees.pk_trainee_id = new.fk_trainees_id 
    GROUP BY courses.FK_CLASS_ID
  ) courses
) 
WHERE trainees.pk_trainee_id = new.fk_trainees_id
```

and does exactly what I expect, recently I migrated my database to another machine and moved and renamed a few tables and columns. So I re-wrote this trigger to:

```
UPDATE main 
SET rsi_total = (
  SELECT SUM(RsiTotal) as RsiTotal 
  FROM (
    SELECT MAX(completed_hrs) as RsiTotal 
    FROM courses 
      LEFT JOIN jac.do_not_add ON courses.fk_class_id = do_not_add.fk_class_id 
      INNER JOIN main ON courses.fk_main_id = main.pk_main_id 
    WHERE do_not_add.fk_class_id IS NULL 
      AND main.pk_main_id = new.fk_main_id 
    GROUP BY courses.FK_CLASS_ID
  ) courses
) 
WHERE main.pk_main_id = new.fk_main_id
```

But I get Error 1093? I looked up this error and it says I can not update a table that is being changed, what I dont understand is why does the old trigger continue to work but not this new?

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to another machine, you probably got a more recent version of MySql, where the optimizer doesn't accept any longer subqueries to access the same table which is being updated.

Look at [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737915/3415269).

Comment: Thank you for that link, Im still not sure how to proceed in order to correct the issue. The link did mention using SET optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge=off'; Dont know what it means yet so some more research is in order.

Comment: Btw, my old machine was running MySQL 5.6, My new is running 5.7 and apparently its a change in the way MySQL functions that prevents it from working.

Comment: @Gustavo1478 Your last comments enforces certainty about where the issue comes from. Regarding your previous comment, it's pretty easy: you merely have to add the `SET optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge=off';` line at the beginning of your query.

Comment: If another SO topic is the straight answer to a question, then flag it as duplicate next time instead of providing an answer!

Comment: @Shadow As a general rule, I agree. But here the OP stated the peculiar case of machine migration, which needed the explanation about a probable version change. It's why I found the other topic was not "the straight answer" to the question.